# How to use vector in R as a foreach-type iterator to apply function to a date frame?

Tags: r

I have a vector of dates:

```
mydates <- seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), length=6, by="1 month")
```

and a data frame with some more data such as (but with a lot more entries):

```
startdate <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-05-15", "2013-05-22"))
enddate <- as.Date(c("2013-02-21", "2013-03-15", "2013-06-15", "2013-07-22"))
state <- c("NY", "NY", "CA", "CA")
df <- data.frame(startdate=startdate, enddate=enddate, state=state)
```

Now I'd like to use each date in the mydates vector to check how many entries existed in each state. That is, I'd like to be able to do these statements

```
result <- subset(df, startdate <= mydates[1] & enddate > mydates[1])
table(result$state)
```

for each element of the mydates vector. I tried various apply functions and the foreach package but nothing's working. Thanks for any suggestions.

*Update*
Per advice below, some of the many things I tried that didn't work:

```
 results <- for(i in 1:length(mydates)) {subset(df, startdate <= mydates[i] & enddate > mydates[i])} 

foreach(i=mydates) %do% { subset(df, startdate<= i & enddate > i) }
```

and creating a separate function

```
myf <- function (mydate,mydf=df) {
x <- subset(mydf, startdate <= mydate & enddate > mydate)

}
```

with the subsetting and trying sapply(mydates, myf)

This
    myresults <- sapply(mydates, myf)

gives me the same results as

```
all_results <- sapply(1:length(mydates), function(x) subset(df, startdate <= mydates[x] & enddate > mydates[x]))
```

below which are

```
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     
startdate 15706    Numeric,2 15737    Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2
enddate   15757    Numeric,2 15779    Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2
state     factor,1 factor,2  factor,1 factor,0  factor,0  factor,2
```

I could be misunderstanding those, but it doesn't appear to show me the number of matching results by state.

Comment: I believe your for-loop there overwrites `results` every time, so you only get the data from the last time thru the loop.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWitthoft. That would explain why I was only getting one result from some of my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... and a other possible solution

```
sapply(mydates, function(x, df){
        ind<-df[ ,"startdate"] <= x & df[,"enddate"] > x
        table(df[ind, "state"])}, df=df)
```

hth

Comment: That works, thanks! I will need to examine that code carefully to see why that function works properly and mine didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
all_results <- sapply(1:length(mydates), function(x) subset(df, startdate <= mydates[x] & enddate > mydates[x])
```

But it would be helpful (per standard SO rules) to post the code you tried so we can point out possible errors.

Comment: Thanks. I tried so many things over the past couple of hours it'd be hard to round them all up :) Including results <- for(i in 1:length(mydates)) 
{subset(df, startdate <= mydates[i] & enddate > mydates[i])} and foreach(i=mydates) %do%
 {
  subset(df, startdate<= i & enddate > i)
}
 and creating a separate function with the subsetting and trying sapply(mydates, myfunction(x))